# How do I programmatically select Material Tree nodes with SelectionModel?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a tree with checkboxes [(let's use Material's example here)](https://stackblitz.com/angular/mndroyqrvbk?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts). I'd like the fruit nodes to begin checked. How do I check those nodes?

I see that `SelectionModel` has a `select()` method that the example passes a node. But in the example, the data the tree is made of is an array of `TodoItemNode`, but the `SelectionModel` contains `TodoItemFlatNode`. The `transformer` method in the example can "flatten" my node (ie. convert `TodoItemNode` to `TodoItemFlatNode`), but that would return a new instance.

How can I programmatically select mat-tree checkboxes to match my data?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To pre-select the fruits node implement the following in an `ngAfterViewInit` for the `TreeChecklistExample` class in the attached stackblitz example.

- This will loop through the `dataNodes` in the `treeControl`
- If `item == 'Fruits'` select node and expand
- Also if `item == 'Groceries'` expand node as it is the parent of Fruits.

  ```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.treeControl.dataNodes.length; i++) {
        if (this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].item == 'Fruits') {
          this.todoItemSelectionToggle(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i]);
          this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i])
        }
        if (this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].item == 'Groceries') {
          this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i])
        }
      }
    }
  ```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2nf2r?embed=1&file=app/tree-checklist-example.html

---

Comment: `NestedTreeControl`s have an undefined `dataNodes` which made the answer impossible. [This github comment](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12469#issuecomment-410441658)  on a related issue suggests that you set it manually until it's resolved.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to use `this.dataSource.data` instead of dataNodes and it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Ashley using dataSource could work, but you have to go through the tree recursively, and make the function return the whole tree to expand.

Answer (score 0):

For `NestedTreeControl`, where `dataNodes` is undefined, you can just go through the datasource instead. This can be done using a recursive function, demonstrated here by looking for it by an `id` property on a `TreeItem` class used to populate the tree. Of course your lookup method can differ depending on the class you have for that.

Once you find the correct node in the `DataSource` data, you can create an array containing the found object and return it. The previous levels of the recursion can then add their own level's found item to the end, so the final result is an array containing the entire sequence to expand, in reverse order, with index 0 as the deepest node.

```
expandTreeToNode(nodeId: number) {
    let selectNode: TreeItem[] | null = this.findTreeNode(this.nestedDataSource.data, nodeId);
    if (selectNode != null && selectNode.length > 0) {
        // expand the returned tree, from shallowest to deepest level
        for (let i : number = selectNode.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            this.nestedTreeControl.expand(selectNode[i]);
        // function to make stuff happen when you click on a node.
        this.setSelectedNode(selectNode[0]);
    }
}

findTreeNode(collection: TreeItem[], nodeId: number) : TreeItem[] | null
{
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; ++i)
    {
        let item : TreeItem = collection[i];
        if (item.id == nodeId)
            return new Array(item);
        let chItem : TreeItem[] | null = this.findTreeNode(item.children, nodeId);
        if (chItem != null) {
            chItem[chItem.length] = item;
            return chItem;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```