# Precheck box in Angular Material Tree

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tree, angular-material

I have an Angular Material Tree I'm displaying. The tree works fine by itself, but I also have a list of names/ids that are already selected values. The data is given to me separately. I haven't been able to figure out how to precheck boxes inside the tree on load.

I've created a Stackblitz here to show my issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukaq9u

My initial thought was to try and look through my selected list and manually toggle the selected in ngInit like so (this doesn't work though):

```
    for (const pg of selectedBoxes) {
      let leaf = new TodoItemFlatNode();
      leaf.item = pg.Product_Group_ID.toString();
      leaf.level = 1;
      leaf.expandable = false;
      this.todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(leaf);
    }
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions? I haven't been able to find any examples online.

Comment: `[checked]="true"` to check the checkbox

Comment: That just checks every single box....

Comment: You asked "how to precheck boxes".

Comment: If you want to conditionally check them, you could use a function to retrieve the state.

Comment: In my code above I loop through and select the selected data to conditionally check the boxes and put them in the checklistSelection, which is being used in the `[checked]` attribute.  But it's not working, hence my question on here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a similar example of what I was looking for [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545096/how-do-i-programmatically-select-material-tree-nodes-with-selectionmodel)

By looping through my existing nodes and comparing them to my existing list of selected data; I can use the existing node, instead of creating a new copy, to toggle the check.

Like so:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this.treeControl.dataNodes.length; i++) {
      for (const pg of selectedBoxes) {
        if (this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].item == pg.Product_Group_Name) {
          this.todoItemSelectionToggle(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i]);
          this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i])
        }
      }
    }
```