# How do I access flattenedData when using MatTreeFlatDataSource

Tags: angular, angular-material, treeview, flatten

After upgrading to **Angular Material - version 12** ("@angular/material": "^12.1.2"). It seems that I cannot access the **_flattenData** property anymore from **MatTreeFlatDataSource**. This part of code use to work before the upgrade:

```
    this.dataSource._flattenedData.value.forEach(item => {
  const issueHasThisItem =
    this.data.exitingItems.findIndex(
      (loopItem: Entity) =>
        (item.level === 1 ||
          this.data.treeModalType === TreeModalType.SOLUTION) &&
        loopItem.id === item.item.id
    ) !== -1;
  if (issueHasThisItem) {
    this.checklistSelection.select(item);
  }
});
```

Now, it seems that _flattenData is read only private and it does not work anymore (according to the latest commit: [Angular Material link](https://github.com/angular/components/commit/4a3ca82c7db02b144e4774d72a5ebea1a26738f1#diff-85b91e331d68fc36cb655de1ffa497937e03049df5a2eddbc1dd3b03d9f63c61)):

```
    Error: src/app/modules/issues/components/issue-impact/tree-modal/tree-modal.component.ts:151:21 - error TS2341: Property '_flattenedData' is private and only accessible within class 'MatTreeFlatDataSource<T, F, K>'.

151     this.dataSource._flattenedData.value.forEach((item) => {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know that this is not the proper way on how to access the flatten data. Are there any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the nodes via `treeControl`:

```
  this.treeControl.dataNodes.forEach(item => {
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53545700/6025248